# Quickbooks Online API using PHP with Curl Oauth

Tags: php, oauth, quickbooks

The documentation for accessing the Quickbooks Online API seems to revolve around creating applications for public use. I'm only interested in developing an app to access my very own Quickbooks file. However, I'm having difficulty authenticating.

I successfully obtain all the necessary codes and can run API calls in the API playground. My preference would be not to use any libraries (including the Quickbooks PHP library as it does not support JSON).

I have spent hours searching but I do not know how to 'sign' the various secrets and codes to obtain the Oauth token needed. Does anyone have working PHP code?

I'd like to simply be able to input in the values and make the API calls via curl.

Answer (score 0):

> I have spent hours searching but I do not know how to 'sign' the various secrets and codes to obtain the Oauth token needed.

You sign the code using OAuth. This is a well documented authentication method, with many implementations.

> Does anyone have working PHP code?

Sure:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/QuickBooks/IPP/OAuth.php#L77
- https://code.google.com/p/oauth-php/
- https://php.net/manual/en/book.oauth.php
- https://pecl.php.net/package/oauth
- https://github.com/Lusitanian/PHPoAuthLib

> My preference would be not to use any libraries

OAuth is not a trivial authentication method. You *should* use a library to sign your requests -- it will save you *a lot* of time vs. implementing your own OAuth signatures.

Comment: Thanks Keith. I followed instructions here http://kwynn.com/t/5/01/QB/QuickBooks_API_example.html which seems to allow me to connect yet no values are returned when I run it.  I just get `null`.  When I run through command line I just get `You are not currently authenticated' I'm honestly lost here. Most APIs I've worked with, you authenticate, you're given a key and voila. Here I'm jumping through a thousand hoops.

Comment: Without seeing code, not really much I can tell you. With that said, that's not the approach I would take. I would start with: https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php  And use this guide: http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/PHP_DevKit_for_QuickBooks_-_Intuit_Partner_Platform_Quick-Start  Because I know it works and I know I can ask here: http://consolibyte.com/forum/ to get help. (Yes, I'm the author -- that was my bit of shameless self-promotion. With that said -- our code actually does work and is easy to debug/troubleshoot, which is more than I can say about Intuit's stuff...)

Comment: Side note: If you want to use things sans-framework (or at least as minimal as possible without making your life miserable), you might still consider initially using what I've recommended above to get going, and then if you post on our forums I can show you how to cut the code down quite easily to be as minimal as possible, and support JSON, with very little effort.

Comment: Thanks Keith for all your help. I ended up going back desktop QB with QODBC. Something I've used for years and I know works.